# Sum the values of the Row Drupal 7 views

Tags: drupal-7, sum, addition

How can i sum the values of the Row with different field in drupal view.
I used view_calc module to sum the column, but now i need to sum the rows data

All should be in the views of drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

If none of available contrib module will help, you may solve with "template override" approach. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/51710/13760